# ConsoleApp docker container requires AspNetCore

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker, visual-studio

I have a simple console application that utilizes standard Microsoft `Host` (`TelegramPoster.Presentation`). I want to build a docker image of it. Here is a `Dockerfile` that Visual Studio creates for me:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TelegramPoster.Presentation/TelegramPoster.Presentation.csproj", "TelegramPoster.Presentation/"]
COPY ["TelegramPoster.Domain/TelegramPoster.Domain.csproj", "TelegramPoster.Domain/"]
COPY ["TelegramPoster.Application/TelegramPoster.Application.csproj", "TelegramPoster.Application/"]
COPY ["TelegramPoster.Infrastructure/TelegramPoster.Infrastructure.csproj", "TelegramPoster.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure.Common/Infrastructure.Common.csproj", "Infrastructure.Common/"]
COPY ["Application.Common/Application.Common.csproj", "Application.Common/"]
COPY ["DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj", "DataAccess/"]
COPY ["Domain.Common/Domain.Common.csproj", "Domain.Common/"]
COPY ["Hosted.Common/Hosted.Common.csproj", "Hosted.Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TelegramPoster.Presentation/TelegramPoster.Presentation.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TelegramPoster.Presentation"
RUN dotnet build "TelegramPoster.Presentation.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TelegramPoster.Presentation.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TelegramPoster.Presentation.dll"]
```

But when it comes to running a docker container based on this image I get the following output in container logs:

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: /app/TelegramPoster.Presentation.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
No frameworks were found.
Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

Where did `AspNetCore.App` come from? Why do I even get this kind of message if I have my image built upon both Runtime and SDK of version 6.0?

Comment: What sort of Host does your console app make? `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`? Something in your project uses ASP.Net's framework, either the console app itself, or a dependent project/library. What is the SDK value at the top of your csproj file?

Comment: Top of the code you posted requires Core 6.0.  Your machine does not have Core loaded.  You need to install Core 6.0 or change the top of the posted code to the version of Net/Core installed on machine. Using a version other than Core 6.0 may or may not work.  Microsoft like to force people to use latest version of Net/Core. I don't like moving latest version since new version of Microsoft Software can have bugs. I like to wait at least 6 months after Microsoft releases new version before using a new version.  Core 6.0 I think is too new to use right now. Better to use Core 5.0 or Net 4.8.

Comment: @gunr2171, It is `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`

Comment: @jdweng, first of all, .NET 6 is almost 10 months old, and secondly, how the hosting environment of docker affects the images themselves? I mean, that is why the image is bulit upon those two layers.

Comment: @jdweng .NET 5.0 is already no longer supported (it's not an LTS release), and .NET 4.8 is a legacy product only fit for maintenance. .NET 6 is the recommended version. Also, the whole point of using a .NET SDK Docker image is that the image already includes the .NET build tools, so you don't need to install them separately.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel : Lots of people are still having issues with NET 6.  There are still bugs.